# Random Forest Regression Implementation in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I want to implement Random forest regression in pyspark after all data preparation. I want sample code for implementation.

Answer (score 0):

From the doc (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressor) :

```
>>> from numpy import allclose
>>> from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
>>> from pyspark.ml.regression import RandomForestRegressor
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([
...     (1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0)),
...     (0.0, Vectors.sparse(1, [], []))], ["label", "features"])
>>> rf = RandomForestRegressor(numTrees=2, maxDepth=2, seed=42)
>>> model = rf.fit(df)
>>> model.featureImportances
SparseVector(1, {0: 1.0})
>>> allclose(model.treeWeights, [1.0, 1.0])
True
>>> test0 = spark.createDataFrame([(Vectors.dense(-1.0),)], ["features"])
>>> model.transform(test0).head().prediction
0.0
>>> model.numFeatures
1
>>> model.trees
[DecisionTreeRegressionModel (uid=...) of depth..., DecisionTreeRegressionModel...]
>>> model.getNumTrees
2
>>> test1 = spark.createDataFrame([(Vectors.sparse(1, [0], [1.0]),)], ["features"])
>>> model.transform(test1).head().prediction
0.5
>>> rfr_path = temp_path + "/rfr"
>>> rf.save(rfr_path)
>>> rf2 = RandomForestRegressor.load(rfr_path)
>>> rf2.getNumTrees()
2
>>> model_path = temp_path + "/rfr_model"
>>> model.save(model_path)
>>> model2 = RandomForestRegressionModel.load(model_path)
>>> model.featureImportances == model2.featureImportances
True
```